# Airportd at 100 % after waking up

Tags: airport

After waking up my computer `airportd` was at 100 %. [Searching for the most prevalent log messages returned no results](https://www.google.com/search?q=CW%20XPCConnection%20__queryScanCacheWith%20Channel%3AssidList%3AlegacyScanSSID%3AmaxAge%3Amax%20MissCount%3AmaxWakeCount%3AmaxAutoJoinCount%3AinterfaceName%3Apriority%3Aerror%3A%5D%3A%20FAILED%20to%20complete%20operation%20within%204.0s%2C%20continuing). Any ideas what might have caused this?

Everything else was normal. Killing airportd fixed the issue but I have other issues with airport (such as it frequently it takes several minutes for it to connect).

```
09:52:24.232981+0100    airportd    -[CWXPCConnection __queryScanCacheWithChannel:ssidList:legacyScanSSID:maxAge:maxMissCount:maxWakeCount:maxAutoJoinCount:interfaceName:priority:error:]: FAILED to complete operation within 4.0s, continuing
09:52:31.353945+0100    airportd    Locale timer fired
09:52:31.354429+0100    airportd    Error: Locale check was suspended (forceCheck 0, localeCheckSuspended 0), exit
09:53:03.294913+0100    kernel  5170661.426466 wlan0.A[945395] setPOWER@31592: [airportd]: Setting power state to 1. stateFlags(20001)
09:53:03.333276+0100    airportd    _getIfListCopy/   410: Added 'IFM_IEEE80211' supported interface '<private>'
09:53:03.357614+0100    airportd    _getIfListCopy/   421: getifaddrs nInterfaces[ 24], count[  3]
09:53:03.357517+0100    airportd    [corewifi] RECV REQ [GET CURR SCAN RESULT] (pid=25924 proc=configd service=com.apple.private.corewifi-xpc intf=(null) uuid=79719 info=(null))
09:53:03.360373+0100    airportd    -[dpsManager handleDPSEventWithType:eventInfo:networkName:BSSID:channelInfo:isCriticalAppInUse:]_block_invoke: Ignoring non-dps events while not in monitoring period/ Ignoring DPS event while in monitoring period
09:53:03.376493+0100    airportd    Locale <DE> was determined at 2022-01-09 09:35:48, has been valid for 17.24 mins [cache timeout 60.00 mins]
09:53:03.488543+0100    airportd    [corewifi] SENT RESP [GET CURR SCAN RESULT] (pid=25924 proc=configd service=com.apple.private.corewifi-xpc intf=(null) uuid=79719 err=2)
09:53:03.617757+0100    airportd    -[WiFiSoftError incrementCount]_block_invoke: Error: SoftError <WiFiToggle> has reached its max occurrence count 100, ignoring
09:53:07.647964+0100    airportd    clearScanCache: FAILED to complete operation within 4.0s, continuing
09:53:37.888957+0100    airportd    Failed to talk to secd after 4 attempts.
09:53:37.968358+0100    airportd    keychain blob version does not support integrity
09:53:38.801995+0100    airportd    [corewifi] RECV REQ [GET CURR SCAN RESULT] (pid=25924 proc=configd service=com.apple.private.corewifi-xpc intf=(null) uuid=52D82 info=(null))
09:53:38.805294+0100    airportd    [corewifi] SENT RESP [GET CURR SCAN RESULT] (pid=25924 proc=configd service=com.apple.private.corewifi-xpc intf=(null) uuid=52D82 err=0)
09:53:38.815637+0100    airportd    [corewifi] LQM: rssi=-67dBm noise=-91dBm snr=24 cca=14.0% ccaSelfTotal=0 ccaOtherTotal=0 interferenceTotal=0 txRate=0.0Mbps txFrames=0 txFail=0 txRetrans=0 txFallbackRate=0.0Mbps rxRate=0.0Mbps rxFrames=0 rxRetryFrames=0
09:53:38.823297+0100    airportd    [corewifi] RECV REQ [GET CURR KNOWN NETWORK] (pid=17976 proc=networkserviceproxy service=com.apple.private.corewifi-xpc intf=(null) uuid=2F6CB info=(null))
09:53:38.885889+0100    airportd    _getIfListCopy/   421: getifaddrs nInterfaces[ 25], count[  3]
09:53:38.888437+0100    airportd    [corewifi] SENT RESP [GET CURR KNOWN NETWORK] (pid=17976 proc=networkserviceproxy service=com.apple.private.corewifi-xpc intf=(null) uuid=2F6CB err=0)
09:53:38.939346+0100    airportd    _getIfListCopy/   421: getifaddrs nInterfaces[ 26], count[  3]
09:53:39.199812+0100    airportd    ERROR: sharingd (26656) is not entitled for com.apple.wifi.join_history, will not allow request
09:53:39.211878+0100    airportd    ERROR: rapportd (26605) is not entitled for com.apple.wifi.join_history, will not allow request
09:53:39.797508+0100    airportd    -[NWConcrete_nw_resolver initWithEndpoint:parameters:path:log_str:] [R1055] created for Hostname#a8da0aac:0 using: generic, attribution: developer
09:53:43.026448+0100    airportd    -[CWInterface(Private) queryScanCacheWithChannels:ssidList:maxAge:maxMissCount:maxWakeCount:maxAutoJoinCount:error:]: FAILED to complete operation within 4.0s, continuing
09:53:44.844608+0100    airportd    __addDeviceUUID: FAILED to complete operation within 4.0s, continuing
09:53:48.832127+0100    airportd    [corewifi] LQM: rssi=-67dBm noise=-86dBm snr=22 cca=14.0% ccaSelfTotal=0 ccaOtherTotal=0 interferenceTotal=0 txRate=520.0Mbps txFrames=158 txFail=0 txRetrans=83 txFallbackRate=130.0Mbps rxRate=351.0Mbps rxFrames=161 rxRetryFrames=8 beaconRecv=5 beaconSched=5 txFwFrames=0 txFwFail=0 txFwRetrans=0
09:53:53.839543+0100    airportd    [corewifi] LQM: rssi=-66dBm noise=-87dBm snr=25 cca=14.0% ccaSelfTotal=0 ccaOtherTotal=0 interferenceTotal=0 txRate=520.0Mbps txFrames=60 txFail=0 txRetrans=52 txFallbackRate=130.0Mbps rxRate=234.0Mbps rxFrames=43 rxRetryFrames=7 beaconRecv=50 beaconSched=50 txFwFrames=46 txFwFail=0 txFwRetrans=0
09:53:54.893083+0100    airportd    [corewifi] RECV REQ [GET SSID] (pid=55767 proc=wifivelocityd service=com.apple.private.corewifi.internal-xpc intf=(null) uuid=2D20F info=(null))
09:53:54.894714+0100    airportd    [corewifi] SENT RESP [GET SSID] (pid=55767 proc=wifivelocityd service=com.apple.private.corewifi.internal-xpc intf=(null) uuid=2D20F err=0)
09:53:54.895312+0100    airportd    [corewifi] RECV REQ [GET SECURITY] (pid=55767 proc=wifivelocityd service=com.apple.private.corewifi.internal-xpc intf=(null) uuid=2D20F info=(null))
09:53:54.897216+0100    airportd    [corewifi] SENT RESP [GET SECURITY] (pid=55767 proc=wifivelocityd service=com.apple.private.corewifi.internal-xpc intf=(null) uuid=2D20F err=0)
09:53:54.897707+0100    airportd    [corewifi] RECV REQ [GET WEP SUBTYPE] (pid=55767 proc=wifivelocityd service=com.apple.private.corewifi.internal-xpc intf=(null) uuid=2D20F info=(null))
09:53:54.899813+0100    airportd    [corewifi] SENT RESP [GET WEP SUBTYPE] (pid=55767 proc=wifivelocityd service=com.apple.private.corewifi.internal-xpc intf=(null) uuid=2D20F err=0)
09:53:54.900319+0100    airportd    [corewifi] RECV REQ [GET WAPI SUBTYPE] (pid=55767 proc=wifivelocityd service=com.apple.private.corewifi.internal-xpc intf=(null) uuid=2D20F info=(null))
09:53:54.902220+0100    airportd    [corewifi] SENT RESP [GET WAPI SUBTYPE] (pid=55767 proc=wifivelocityd service=com.apple.private.corewifi.internal-xpc intf=(null) uuid=2D20F err=0)
09:53:54.916353+0100    airportd    [corewifi] RECV REQ [GET CURR SCAN RESULT] (pid=55767 proc=wifivelocityd service=com.apple.private.corewifi.internal-xpc intf=(null) uuid=2D20F info=(null))
09:53:54.920308+0100    airportd    [corewifi] SENT RESP [GET CURR SCAN RESULT] (pid=55767 proc=wifivelocityd service=com.apple.private.corewifi.internal-xpc intf=(null) uuid=2D20F err=0)
09:53:54.944144+0100    airportd    [corewifi] RECV REQ [GET PHY MODE] (pid=55767 proc=wifivelocityd service=com.apple.private.corewifi.internal-xpc intf=(null) uuid=2D20F info=(null))
09:53:54.953649+0100    airportd    [corewifi] SENT RESP [GET PHY MODE] (pid=55767 proc=wifivelocityd service=com.apple.private.corewifi.internal-xpc intf=(null) uuid=2D20F err=0)
09:53:54.957644+0100    airportd    [corewifi] RECV REQ [GET CURR KNOWN NETWORK] (pid=55767 proc=wifivelocityd service=com.apple.private.corewifi.internal-xpc intf=(null) uuid=2D20F info=(null))
09:53:54.961699+0100    airportd    [corewifi] SENT RESP [GET CURR KNOWN NETWORK] (pid=55767 proc=wifivelocityd service=com.apple.private.corewifi.internal-xpc intf=(null) uuid=2D20F err=0)
09:53:58.852016+0100    airportd    [corewifi] LQM: rssi=-66dBm noise=-87dBm snr=20 cca=14.0% ccaSelfTotal=0 ccaOtherTotal=0 interferenceTotal=0 txRate=520.0Mbps txFrames=83 txFail=0 txRetrans=50 txFallbackRate=117.0Mbps rxRate=351.0Mbps rxFrames=76 rxRetryFrames=3 beaconRecv=49 beaconSched=49 txFwFrames=60 txFwFail=0 txFwRetrans=0
09:54:03.861340+0100    airportd    [corewifi] LQM: rssi=-66dBm noise=-89dBm snr=18 cca=11.0% ccaSelfTotal=2 ccaOtherTotal=6 interferenceTotal=2 txRate=390.0Mbps txFrames=66 txFail=0 txRetrans=28 txFallbackRate=78.0Mbps rxRate=234.0Mbps rxFrames=63 rxRetryFrames=10 beaconRecv=68 beaconSched=71 txFwFrames=53 txFwFail=0 txFwRetrans=4
09:54:08.878798+0100    airportd    [corewifi] LQM: rssi=-64dBm noise=-88dBm snr=22 cca=11.0% ccaSelfTotal=3 ccaOtherTotal=7 interferenceTotal=1 txRate=520.0Mbps txFrames=243 txFail=0 txRetrans=94 txFallbackRate=6.5Mbps rxRate=351.0Mbps rxFrames=212 rxRetryFrames=6 beaconRecv=38 beaconSched=49 txFwFrames=45 txFwFail=0 txFwRetrans=0
09:54:13.887029+0100    airportd    [corewifi] LQM: rssi=-64dBm noise=-88dBm snr=20 cca=11.0% ccaSelfTotal=1 ccaOtherTotal=9 interferenceTotal=0 txRate=351.0Mbps txFrames=226 txFail=0 txRetrans=36 txFallbackRate=78.0Mbps rxRate=351.0Mbps rxFrames=190 rxRetryFrames=8 beaconRecv=54 beaconSched=65 txFwFrames=73 txFwFail=0 txFwRetrans=3
09:54:18.899513+0100    airportd    [corewifi] LQM: rssi=-64dBm noise=-88dBm snr=25 cca=11.0% ccaSelfTotal=1 ccaOtherTotal=9 interferenceTotal=0 txRate=390.0Mbps txFrames=34 txFail=0 txRetrans=7 txFallbackRate=86.7Mbps rxRate=468.0Mbps rxFrames=29 rxRetryFrames=0 beaconRecv=44 beaconSched=49 txFwFrames=60 txFwFail=0 txFwRetrans=0
09:54:23.913774+0100    airportd    [corewifi] LQM: rssi=-64dBm noise=-89dBm snr=24 cca=11.0% ccaSelfTotal=1 ccaOtherTotal=8 interferenceTotal=0 txRate=390.0Mbps txFrames=45 txFail=0 txRetrans=28 txFallbackRate=86.7Mbps rxRate=351.0Mbps rxFrames=42 rxRetryFrames=9 beaconRecv=42 beaconSched=49 txFwFrames=50 txFwFail=0 txFwRetrans=1
09:54:28.922554+0100    airportd    [corewifi] LQM: rssi=-65dBm noise=-88dBm snr=23 cca=10.0% ccaSelfTotal=1 ccaOtherTotal=8 interferenceTotal=0 txRate=351.0Mbps txFrames=35 txFail=0 txRetrans=28 txFallbackRate=78.0Mbps rxRate=351.0Mbps rxFrames=31 rxRetryFrames=4 beaconRecv=37 beaconSched=49 txFwFrames=51 txFwFail=0 txFwRetrans=5
09:54:31.350125+0100    airportd    Locale <DE> was determined at 2022-01-09 09:35:48, has been valid for 18.71 mins [cache timeout 60.00 mins]
09:54:33.932961+0100    airportd    [corewifi] LQM: rssi=-67dBm noise=-87dBm snr=21 cca=10.0% ccaSelfTotal=1 ccaOtherTotal=7 interferenceTotal=1 txRate=390.0Mbps txFrames=84 txFail=0 txRetrans=28 txFallbackRate=78.0Mbps rxRate=351.0Mbps rxFrames=67 rxRetryFrames=6 beaconRecv=46 beaconSched=49 txFwFrames=30 txFwFail=0 txFwRetrans=0
09:54:38.951476+0100    airportd    [corewifi] LQM: rssi=-66dBm noise=-88dBm snr=20 cca=13.0% ccaSelfTotal=2 ccaOtherTotal=9 interferenceTotal=1 txRate=351.0Mbps txFrames=112 txFail=0 txRetrans=43 txFallbackRate=78.0Mbps rxRate=351.0Mbps rxFrames=116 rxRetryFrames=20 beaconRecv=49 beaconSched=50 txFwFrames=18 txFwFail=0 txFwRetrans=2
09:54:41.012202+0100    airportd    [corewifi] RECV REQ [GET CURR SCAN RESULT] (pid=25924 proc=configd service=com.apple.private.corewifi-xpc intf=(null) uuid=78BC2 info=(null))
09:54:41.022070+0100    airportd    [corewifi] SENT RESP [GET CURR SCAN RESULT] (pid=25924 proc=configd service=com.apple.private.corewifi-xpc intf=(null) uuid=78BC2 err=0)
09:54:43.963134+0100    airportd    [corewifi] LQM: rssi=-64dBm noise=-88dBm snr=20 cca=11.0% ccaSelfTotal=1 ccaOtherTotal=8 interferenceTotal=0 txRate=468.0Mbps txFrames=81 txFail=0 txRetrans=22 txFallbackRate=117.0Mbps rxRate=351.0Mbps rxFrames=56 rxRetryFrames=19 beaconRecv=36 beaconSched=49 txFwFrames=23 txFwFail=0 txFwRetrans=0
09:54:48.982505+0100    airportd    [corewifi] LQM: rssi=-66dBm noise=-88dBm snr=19 cca=11.0% ccaSelfTotal=0 ccaOtherTotal=9 interferenceTotal=0 txRate=390.0Mbps txFrames=81 txFail=0 txRetrans=21 txFallbackRate=86.7Mbps rxRate=351.0Mbps rxFrames=62 rxRetryFrames=9 beaconRecv=30 beaconSched=49 txFwFrames=42 txFwFail=0 txFwRetrans=0
09:54:53.991415+0100    airportd    [corewifi] LQM: rssi=-66dBm noise=-88dBm snr=20 cca=11.0% ccaSelfTotal=0 ccaOtherTotal=9 interferenceTotal=0 txRate=390.0Mbps txFrames=258 txFail=0 txRetrans=38 txFallbackRate=78.0Mbps rxRate=351.0Mbps rxFrames=482 rxRetryFrames=23 beaconRecv=47 beaconSched=49 txFwFrames=35 txFwFail=0 txFwRetrans=8
09:54:58.997426+0100    airportd    [corewifi] LQM: rssi=-64dBm noise=-88dBm snr=24 cca=11.0% ccaSelfTotal=0 ccaOtherTotal=9 interferenceTotal=0 txRate=390.0Mbps txFrames=116 txFail=0 txRetrans=35 txFallbackRate=78.0Mbps rxRate=351.0Mbps rxFrames=116 rxRetryFrames=5 beaconRecv=45 beaconSched=49 txFwFrames=60 txFwFail=0 txFwRetrans=4
09:55:04.002253+0100    airportd    [corewifi] LQM: rssi=-64dBm noise=-87dBm snr=20 cca=11.0% ccaSelfTotal=0 ccaOtherTotal=9 interferenceTotal=0 txRate=390.0Mbps txFrames=94 txFail=0 txRetrans=23 txFallbackRate=78.0Mbps rxRate=468.0Mbps rxFrames=340 rxRetryFrames=59 beaconRecv=44 beaconSched=49 txFwFrames=71 txFwFail=0 txFwRetrans=4
09:55:09.024821+0100    airportd    [corewifi] LQM: rssi=-67dBm noise=-87dBm snr=23 cca=11.0% ccaSelfTotal=0 ccaOtherTotal=9 interferenceTotal=0 txRate=390.0Mbps txFrames=90 txFail=0 txRetrans=57 txFallbackRate=78.0Mbps rxRate=351.0Mbps rxFrames=145 rxRetryFrames=18 beaconRecv=55 beaconSched=56 txFwFrames=65 txFwFail=0 txFwRetrans=15
09:55:14.036066+0100    airportd    [corewifi] LQM: rssi=-67dBm noise=-87dBm snr=21 cca=11.0% ccaSelfTotal=0 ccaOtherTotal=9 interferenceTotal=0 txRate=390.0Mbps txFrames=44 txFail=0 txRetrans=8 txFallbackRate=86.7Mbps rxRate=351.0Mbps rxFrames=40 rxRetryFrames=7 beaconRecv=48 beaconSched=49 txFwFrames=66 txFwFail=0 txFwRetrans=8
09:55:19.046382+0100    airportd    [corewifi] LQM: rssi=-65dBm noise=-87dBm snr=26 cca=11.0% ccaSelfTotal=0 ccaOtherTotal=9 interferenceTotal=0 txRate=390.0Mbps txFrames=32 txFail=0 txRetrans=16 txFallbackRate=78.0Mbps rxRate=351.0Mbps rxFrames=27 rxRetryFrames=1 beaconRecv=1 beaconSched=1 txFwFrames=67 txFwFail=0 txFwRetrans=8
09:55:24.059227+0100    airportd    [corewifi] LQM: rssi=-65dBm noise=-87dBm snr=20 cca=11.0% ccaSelfTotal=0 ccaOtherTotal=9 interferenceTotal=0 txRate=390.0Mbps txFrames=68 txFail=0 txRetrans=12 txFallbackRate=86.7Mbps rxRate=351.0Mbps rxFrames=104 rxRetryFrames=18 beaconRecv=47 beaconSched=49 txFwFrames=68 txFwFail=0 txFwRetrans=12
09:55:29.068907+0100    airportd    [corewifi] LQM: rssi=-65dBm noise=-87dBm snr=23 cca=11.0% ccaSelfTotal=0 ccaOtherTotal=9 interferenceTotal=0 txRate=468.0Mbps txFrames=54 txFail=0 txRetrans=14 txFallbackRate=117.0Mbps rxRate=351.0Mbps rxFrames=60 rxRetryFrames=3 beaconRecv=54 beaconSched=57 txFwFrames=71 txFwFail=0 txFwRetrans=6
09:55:34.083101+0100    airportd    [corewifi] LQM: rssi=-63dBm noise=-87dBm snr=26 cca=11.0% ccaSelfTotal=0 ccaOtherTotal=9 interferenceTotal=0 txRate=520.0Mbps txFrames=17 txFail=0 txRetrans=10 txFallbackRate=117.0Mbps rxRate=234.0Mbps rxFrames=18 rxRetryFrames=4 beaconRecv=44 beaconSched=49 txFwFrames=61 txFwFail=0 txFwRetrans=0
09:55:39.095767+0100    airportd    [corewifi] LQM: rssi=-65dBm noise=-87dBm snr=23 cca=11.0% ccaSelfTotal=0 ccaOtherTotal=9 interferenceTotal=0 txRate=520.0Mbps txFrames=38 txFail=0 txRetrans=26 txFallbackRate=117.0Mbps rxRate=351.0Mbps rxFrames=28 rxRetryFrames=0 beaconRecv=61 beaconSched=63 txFwFrames=71 txFwFail=0 txFwRetrans=7
09:55:44.104506+0100    airportd    [corewifi] LQM: rssi=-65dBm noise=-88dBm snr=24 cca=11.0% ccaSelfTotal=0 ccaOtherTotal=9 interferenceTotal=0 txRate=390.0Mbps txFrames=57 txFail=0 txRetrans=19 txFallbackRate=78.0Mbps rxRate=351.0Mbps rxFrames=41 rxRetryFrames=3 beaconRecv=47 beaconSched=50 txFwFrames=69 txFwFail=0 txFwRetrans=9
09:55:49.112567+0100    airportd    [corewifi] LQM: rssi=-65dBm noise=-88dBm snr=22 cca=11.0% ccaSelfTotal=0 ccaOtherTotal=9 interferenceTotal=0 txRate=520.0Mbps txFrames=43 txFail=0 txRetrans=19 txFallbackRate=117.0Mbps rxRate=351.0Mbps rxFrames=39 rxRetryFrames=11 beaconRecv=52 beaconSched=52 txFwFrames=72 txFwFail=0 txFwRetrans=6
09:55:54.124459+0100    airportd    [corewifi] LQM: rssi=-63dBm noise=-88dBm snr=23 cca=11.0% ccaSelfTotal=0 ccaOtherTotal=9 interferenceTotal=0 txRate=526.5Mbps txFrames=39 txFail=0 txRetrans=33 txFallbackRate=175.5Mbps rxRate=351.0Mbps rxFrames=37 rxRetryFrames=6 beaconRecv=47 beaconSched=50 txFwFrames=74 txFwFail=0 txFwRetrans=3
09:55:59.130549+0100    airportd    [corewifi] LQM: rssi=-63dBm noise=-88dBm snr=22 cca=11.0% ccaSelfTotal=0 ccaOtherTotal=9 interferenceTotal=0 txRate=468.0Mbps txFrames=242 txFail=0 txRetrans=51 txFallbackRate=117.0Mbps rxRate=351.0Mbps rxFrames=255 rxRetryFrames=8 beaconRecv=46 beaconSched=48 txFwFrames=68 txFwFail=0 txFwRetrans=13
09:56:04.140877+0100    airportd    [corewifi] LQM: rssi=-66dBm noise=-88dBm snr=24 cca=11.0% ccaSelfTotal=0 ccaOtherTotal=9 interferenceTotal=0 txRate=520.0Mbps txFrames=47 txFail=0 txRetrans=45 txFallbackRate=117.0Mbps rxRate=175.5Mbps rxFrames=33 rxRetryFrames=4 beaconRecv=31 beaconSched=31 txFwFrames=67 txFwFail=0 txFwRetrans=3
09:56:09.152780+0100    airportd    [corewifi] LQM: rssi=-64dBm noise=-88dBm snr=20 cca=11.0% ccaSelfTotal=0 ccaOtherTotal=9 interferenceTotal=0 txRate=351.0Mbps txFrames=53 txFail=0 txRetrans=11 txFallbackRate=78.0Mbps rxRate=351.0Mbps rxFrames=45 rxRetryFrames=7 beaconRecv=49 beaconSched=49 txFwFrames=19 txFwFail=0 txFwRetrans=0
09:56:13.694963+0100    airportd    [corewifi] RECV REQ [GET CURR SCAN RESULT] (pid=25924 proc=configd service=com.apple.private.corewifi-xpc intf=(null) uuid=8F832 info=(null))
09:56:13.702411+0100    airportd    [corewifi] SENT RESP [GET CURR SCAN RESULT] (pid=25924 proc=configd service=com.apple.private.corewifi-xpc intf=(null) uuid=8F832 err=0)
09:56:14.164052+0100    airportd    [corewifi] LQM: rssi=-65dBm noise=-88dBm snr=20 cca=11.0% ccaSelfTotal=0 ccaOtherTotal=9 interferenceTotal=0 txRate=390.0Mbps txFrames=66 txFail=0 txRetrans=0 txFallbackRate=86.7Mbps rxRate=351.0Mbps rxFrames=79 rxRetryFrames=3 beaconRecv=49 beaconSched=49 txFwFrames=14 txFwFail=0 txFwRetrans=3
09:56:19.175967+0100    airportd    [corewifi] LQM: rssi=-65dBm noise=-88dBm snr=21 cca=11.0% ccaSelfTotal=0 ccaOtherTotal=9 interferenceTotal=0 txRate=390.0Mbps txFrames=77 txFail=0 txRetrans=15 txFallbackRate=86.7Mbps rxRate=351.0Mbps rxFrames=74 rxRetryFrames=7 beaconRecv=49 beaconSched=49 txFwFrames=8 txFwFail=0 txFwRetrans=0
09:56:24.197489+0100    airportd    [corewifi] LQM: rssi=-65dBm noise=-88dBm snr=19 cca=11.0% ccaSelfTotal=0 ccaOtherTotal=9 interferenceTotal=0 txRate=390.0Mbps txFrames=84 txFail=0 txRetrans=37 txFallbackRate=78.0Mbps rxRate=351.0Mbps rxFrames=81 rxRetryFrames=10 beaconRecv=49 beaconSched=49 txFwFrames=12 txFwFail=0 txFwRetrans=0
09:56:29.204668+0100    airportd    [corewifi] LQM: rssi=-65dBm noise=-88dBm snr=23 cca=11.0% ccaSelfTotal=0 ccaOtherTotal=9 interferenceTotal=0 txRate=390.0Mbps txFrames=40 txFail=0 txRetrans=6 txFallbackRate=78.0Mbps rxRate=351.0Mbps rxFrames=26 rxRetryFrames=4 beaconRecv=49 beaconSched=49 txFwFrames=31 txFwFail=0 txFwRetrans=1
09:56:31.348162+0100    airportd    Locale <DE> was determined at 2022-01-09 09:35:48, has been valid for 20.71 mins [cache timeout 60.00 mins]
09:56:34.212452+0100    airportd    [corewifi] LQM: rssi=-65dBm noise=-88dBm snr=22 cca=11.0% ccaSelfTotal=0 ccaOtherTotal=9 interferenceTotal=0 txRate=520.0Mbps txFrames=52 txFail=0 txRetrans=28 txFallbackRate=117.0Mbps rxRate=351.0Mbps rxFrames=42 rxRetryFrames=6 beaconRecv=60 beaconSched=62 txFwFrames=62 txFwFail=0 txFwRetrans=2
09:56:39.229389+0100    airportd    [corewifi] LQM: rssi=-65dBm noise=-88dBm snr=22 cca=11.0% ccaSelfTotal=0 ccaOtherTotal=9 interferenceTotal=0 txRate=468.0Mbps txFrames=38 txFail=0 txRetrans=39 txFallbackRate=117.0Mbps rxRate=234.0Mbps rxFrames=30 rxRetryFrames=3 beaconRecv=47 beaconSched=49 txFwFrames=68 txFwFail=0 txFwRetrans=1
09:56:44.249659+0100    airportd    [corewifi] LQM: rssi=-65dBm noise=-88dBm snr=22 cca=11.0% ccaSelfTotal=0 ccaOtherTotal=9 interferenceTotal=0 txRate=351.0Mbps txFrames=67 txFail=0 txRetrans=18 txFallbackRate=78.0Mbps rxRate=351.0Mbps rxFrames=54 rxRetryFrames=4 beaconRecv=47 beaconSched=49 txFwFrames=70 txFwFail=0 txFwRetrans=4
09:56:49.263482+0100    airportd    [corewifi] LQM: rssi=-64dBm noise=-87dBm snr=20 cca=11.0% ccaSelfTotal=0 ccaOtherTotal=9 interferenceTotal=0 txRate=292.5Mbps txFrames=79 txFail=0 txRetrans=13 txFallbackRate=78.0Mbps rxRate=351.0Mbps rxFrames=80 rxRetryFrames=12 beaconRecv=47 beaconSched=49 txFwFrames=79 txFwFail=0 txFwRetrans=9
09:56:54.269445+0100    airportd    [corewifi] LQM: rssi=-65dBm noise=-87dBm snr=21 cca=11.0% ccaSelfTotal=0 ccaOtherTotal=9 interferenceTotal=0 txRate=520.0Mbps txFrames=74 txFail=0 txRetrans=48 txFallbackRate=117.0Mbps rxRate=234.0Mbps rxFrames=69 rxRetryFrames=15 beaconRecv=45 beaconSched=49 txFwFrames=69 txFwFail=0 txFwRetrans=5
09:56:59.288376+0100    airportd    [corewifi] LQM: rssi=-66dBm noise=-87dBm snr=21 cca=11.0% ccaSelfTotal=0 ccaOtherTotal=9 interferenceTotal=0 txRate=520.0Mbps txFrames=121 txFail=0 txRetrans=44 txFallbackRate=117.0Mbps rxRate=351.0Mbps rxFrames=140 rxRetryFrames=5 beaconRecv=47 beaconSched=49 txFwFrames=79 txFwFail=0 txFwRetrans=1
09:57:04.295888+0100    airportd    [corewifi] LQM: rssi=-67dBm noise=-88dBm snr=24 cca=11.0% ccaSelfTotal=0 ccaOtherTotal=9 interferenceTotal=0 txRate=520.0Mbps txFrames=28 txFail=0 txRetrans=31 txFallbackRate=117.0Mbps rxRate=351.0Mbps rxFrames=18 rxRetryFrames=4 beaconRecv=49 beaconSched=50 txFwFrames=71 txFwFail=0 txFwRetrans=0
09:57:09.308527+0100    airportd    [corewifi] LQM: rssi=-65dBm noise=-87dBm snr=20 cca=11.0% ccaSelfTotal=0 ccaOtherTotal=9 interferenceTotal=0 txRate=390.0Mbps txFrames=36 txFail=0 txRetrans=18 txFallbackRate=86.7Mbps rxRate=234.0Mbps rxFrames=34 rxRetryFrames=8 beaconRecv=45 beaconSched=49 txFwFrames=45 txFwFail=0 txFwRetrans=0
```

Comment: So the 100% CPU utilization issue hasn’t recurred?

Comment: @pion No, but haven't tried either.